# How do I pass in a field to filter a Django model?

Tags: python, django, string, model, filter

I'm have a function that accepts two parameters: filter_field and filter_value. I want to filter my model like so:

```
Alert.objects.filter(filter_field=filter_value)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'filter_field' into field. Choices are ...
```

Is there way to pass in the string that is being stored in filter_field, and not the literal string 'filter_field'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass keyword arguments to filter:

```
kwargs = {filter_field: filter_value}
Alert.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```